# Container section - how to align this to be centered?

Tags: html, css

I have a question about my container class in web site www.deks.org.rs 
When you scroll on "Sponzori" (Staff section in HTML), you can see 3 logos of sponsors. In template I have got from web this container looks like 4*x matrix. I have only 3 objects here and I want to be centered like there is 4 objects (I think you understand what I wanted to say). How is it possible? 
HTML and CSS files are attached. 
Thank you in advance!

```css
/*-- Staff section --*/

section.staff-agileinfo {
  padding: 100px 0;
}

section.staff-agileinfo h3.text-center {
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: normal;
  color: #000;
  font-family: 'Trebuchet MS', sans-serif;
  padding-bottom: 50px;
}

.view {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 10px solid #f72d2d;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px #e6e6e6;
  -moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px #e6e6e6;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px #e6e6e6;
  cursor: default;
}

.view .mask,
.view .content {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.view img {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}

.view h4 {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 17px;
  padding: 10px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  margin: 150px 0 0 0;
  font-family: 'Trebuchet MS', sans-serif;
}

.view ul.team-social {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 30px 0;
}

.view ul.team-social li {
  display: inline-block;
}

.view ul.team-social li a i.fa {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 40px;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 50%;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
  -moz-border-radius: 50%;
  -o-border-radius: 50%;
  -ms-border-radius: 50%;
}

.view ul.team-social li a:hover i.fa {
  -webkit-animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
  animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
}

.view ul.team-social li a i.fa.fa-facebook {
  background-color: #3b5998;
  color: #fff;
}

.view ul.team-social li a i.fa.fa-youtube {
  background-color: #cd201f;
  color: #fff;
}

.view ul.team-social li a i.fa.fa-twitter {
  background-color: #1da1f2;
  color: #fff;
}

.view ul.team-social li a i.fa.fa-google-plus {
  background-color: #dd4b39;
  color: #fff;
}

.view ul.team-social li a i.fa.fa-linkedin {
  background-color: #0077b5;
  color: #fff;
}

.view p.info {
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 7px 14px;
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 1px #000;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 1px #000;
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px #000;
}

.view p.info: hover {
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #000;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #000;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px #000;
}

.view-eighth .mask {
  background-color: rgba(247, 186, 45, 0.55);
  top: -200px;
  -ms-filter: "progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)";
  filter: alpha(opacity=0);
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-out 0.5s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-out 0.5s;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-out 0.5s;
  -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-out 0.5s;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-out 0.5s;
}

.view-eighth h4 {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-200px);
  -moz-transform: translateY(-200px);
  -o-transform: translateY(-200px);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-200px);
  transform: translateY(-200px);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out 0.1s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out 0.1s;
  -o-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out 0.1s;
  -ms-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out 0.1s;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out 0.1s;
}

.view-eighth ul.team-social {
  color: #333;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-200px);
  -moz-transform: translateY(-200px);
  -o-transform: translateY(-200px);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-200px);
  transform: translateY(-200px);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out 0.2s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out 0.2s;
  -o-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out 0.2s;
  -ms-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out 0.2s;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out 0.2s;
}

.view-eighth p.info {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-200px);
  -moz-transform: translateY(-200px);
  -o-transform: translateY(-200px);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-200px);
  transform: translateY(-200px);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out 0.3s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out 0.3s;
  -o-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out 0.3s;
  -ms-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out 0.3s;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out 0.3s;
}

.view-eighth:hover .mask {
  -ms-filter: "progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100)";
  filter: alpha(opacity=100);
  opacity: 1;
  top: 0px;
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0s;
  -moz-transition-delay: 0s;
  -o-transition-delay: 0s;
  -ms-transition-delay: 0s;
  transition-delay: 0s;
  -webkit-animation: bounceY 0.9s linear;
  -moz-animation: bounceY 0.9s linear;
  -ms-animation: bounceY 0.9s linear;
  animation: bounceY 0.9s linear;
}

.view-eighth:hover h4 {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(0px);
  -moz-transform: translateY(0px);
  -o-transform: translateY(0px);
  -ms-transform: translateY(0px);
  transform: translateY(0px);
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0.4s;
  -moz-transition-delay: 0.4s;
  -o-transition-delay: 0.4s;
  -ms-transition-delay: 0.4s;
  transition-delay: 0.4s;
}

.view-eighth:hover ul.team-social {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(0px);
  -moz-transform: translateY(0px);
  -o-transform: translateY(0px);
  -ms-transform: translateY(0px);
  transform: translateY(0px);
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0.2s;
  -moz-transition-delay: 0.2s;
  -o-transition-delay: 0.2s;
  -ms-transition-delay: 0.2s;
  transition-delay: 0.2s;
}

.view-eighth:hover p.info {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(0px);
  -moz-transform: translateY(0px);
  -o-transform: translateY(0px);
  -ms-transform: translateY(0px);
  transform: translateY(0px);
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0s;
  -moz-transition-delay: 0s;
  -o-transition-delay: 0s;
  -ms-transition-delay: 0s;
  transition-delay: 0s;
}

@keyframes bounceY {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(-205px);
  }
  40% {
    transform: translateY(-100px);
  }
  65% {
    transform: translateY(-52px);
  }
  82% {
    transform: translateY(-25px);
  }
  92% {
    transform: translateY(-12px);
  }
  55%,
  75%,
  87%,
  97%,
  100% {
    transform: translateY(0px);
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes bounceY {
  0% {
    -moz-transform: translateY(-205px);
  }
  40% {
    -moz-transform: translateY(-100px);
  }
  65% {
    -moz-transform: translateY(-52px);
  }
  82% {
    -moz-transform: translateY(-25px);
  }
  92% {
    -moz-transform: translateY(-12px);
  }
  55%,
  75%,
  87%,
  97%,
  100% {
    -moz-transform: translateY(0px);
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes bounceY {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-205px);
  }
  40% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-100px);
  }
  65% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-52px);
  }
  82% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-25px);
  }
  92% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-12px);
  }
  55%,
  75%,
  87%,
  97%,
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0px);
  }
}
```

```html
<section class="staff-agileinfo" id="team">
  <div class="container">
    <h3 class="text-center">Sponzori</h3>
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 team-agile1" data-aos="flip-up">
      <div class="view view-eighth">
        <img src="images/nn.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive" />
        <div class="mask">
          <h4>Novo Nordisk</h4>
          <p class="info">Generalni pokrovitelj</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 team-agile2" data-aos="flip-up">
      <div class="view view-eighth">
        <img src="images/me.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive" />
        <div class="mask">
          <h4>Merck</h4>
          <p class="info">Partner kongresa</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 team-agile3" data-aos="flip-up">
      <div class="view view-eighth">
        <img src="images/ro.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive" />
        <div class="mask">
          <h4>Roche</h4>
          <p class="info">Partner kongresa</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: _I have only 3 objects here and I want to be centered like there is 4 objects_ What do you mean by this?

Comment: I think he wants to center it with each object being 25%

Comment: @zgood  I want to center those three logos on the screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would take the `<h3>` out of the container, and make the container be:

```
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
```

Your code would be:

```css
/*-- Staff section --*/
section.staff-agileinfo {
    padding: 100px 0;
}
section.staff-agileinfo h3.text-center {
 font-size:40px;
 font-weight:normal;
 color:#000;
 font-family: 'Trebuchet MS', sans-serif;
 padding-bottom:50px;
}

section.staff-agileinfo > .container{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.view {
   width:100%;
   height:auto;
   margin:0 auto;
   border: 10px solid #f72d2d;
   overflow: hidden;
   position: relative;
   text-align: center;
   -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px #e6e6e6;
   -moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px #e6e6e6;
   box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px #e6e6e6;
   cursor: default;
}
.view .mask,.view .content {
   width:100%;
   height:100%;
   position: absolute;
   overflow: hidden;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
}
.view img {
   display: block;
   position: relative;
}
.view h4 {
   text-transform: uppercase;
   color: #fff;
   text-align: center;
   position: relative;
   font-size: 17px;
   padding: 10px;
   background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
   margin: 150px 0 0 0;
   font-family: 'Trebuchet MS', sans-serif;
}
.view ul.team-social {
 text-align:center;
 padding:30px 0;
}
.view ul.team-social li {
 display:inline-block;
}
.view ul.team-social li a i.fa {
 width:40px;
 height:40px;
 text-align:center;
 line-height:40px;
 font-size:18px;
 color:#fff;
 border-radius:50%;
 -webkit-border-radius:50%;
 -moz-border-radius:50%;
 -o-border-radius:50%;
 -ms-border-radius:50%;
}
.view ul.team-social li a:hover i.fa {
 -webkit-animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
 animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
}
.view ul.team-social li a i.fa.fa-facebook {
 background-color:#3b5998;
 color:#fff;
}
.view ul.team-social li a i.fa.fa-youtube {
 background-color:#cd201f;
 color:#fff;
}
.view ul.team-social li a i.fa.fa-twitter {
 background-color:#1da1f2;
 color:#fff;
}
.view ul.team-social li a i.fa.fa-google-plus {
 background-color:#dd4b39;
 color:#fff;
}
.view ul.team-social li a i.fa.fa-linkedin {
 background-color:#0077b5;
 color:#fff;
}
.view p.info {
   text-decoration: none;
   padding: 7px 14px;
   background: #000;
   color: #fff;
   text-transform: uppercase;
   -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 1px #000;
   -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 1px #000;
   box-shadow: 0 0 1px #000;
}
.view p.info: hover {
   -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #000;
   -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #000;
   box-shadow: 0 0 5px #000;
}
```

```html
<!-- Staff section  --> 
<section class="staff-agileinfo" id="team">
  <h3 class="text-center">Sponzori</h3>
 <div class="container">
  <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 team-agile1" data-aos="flip-up">
   <div class="view view-eighth">
                <img src="images/nn.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive"/>
                <div class="mask">
    <h4>Novo Nordisk</h4>
     
                    <p class="info">Generalni pokrovitelj</p>
                </div>
            </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 team-agile2" data-aos="flip-up">
   <div class="view view-eighth">
              <img src="images/me.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive"/>
                <div class="mask">
                    <h4>Merck</h4>
     
                    <p class="info">Partner kongresa</p>
                </div>
            </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 team-agile3" data-aos="flip-up">
   <div class="view view-eighth">
                <img src="images/ro.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive"/>
                <div class="mask">
                    <h4>Roche</h4>
                   
                    <p class="info">Partner kongresa</p>
                </div>
            </div>
  </div>

  
 </div>
</section> 
<!-- /Staff section -->
```

Hope this helps!